# How to get property based CSS styles to work with local rule references in Material-UI and JSS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I cannot find a way to get both a [local rule reference](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) (named `'& $value'` in the code below) to fully work in conjunction with [using functions for CSS definitions](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props). Any CSS properties that are defined using a function accepting a `StyleProperties` object and returning a CSS value are simply ignored when defined for rules that reference other local rules; please see code and comments:

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { Theme, makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import clsx from "clsx";

type StyleProperties = {
  scale: number;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: (props: StyleProperties) => {
      const size = `${2.0 * props.scale}rem`;

      return {
        position: "relative",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        width: size,
        height: size,
        "& > div": {
          position: "absolute"
        }
      };
    },

    value: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      textAlign: "center",
      lineHeight: (props: StyleProperties) => `${2.0 * props.scale}rem`
    },

    static: {
      "& $value": {
        // Following are OK
        color: theme.palette.action.disabled,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.disabledBackground,

        // Ignored
        border: (props: StyleProperties) =>
          `${0.0625 * props.scale}rem solid red`

        // Comment out above line and uncomment the following to see expected output
        // if the value 2.0 was passed in through props.
        //border: `${ 0.0625 * 2.0 }rem solid red`,
      }
    }
  })
);

type ValueProperties = {
  value: string;
  scale: number;
};

function Value(props: ValueProperties) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return <div className={clsx(classes.value)}>{props.value}</div>;
}

type CellProperties = {
  static: boolean;
  scale: number;
};

function Cell(props: CellProperties) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <div className={clsx(classes.root, { [classes.static]: props.static })}>
      <Value value="value" scale={props.scale} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Cell static={false} scale={2.0} />
      <Cell static={true} scale={2.0} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also tried using a function accepting my `StyleProperties` object at both `static` and `'& $value'` rule levels rather than at the CSS Property levels, but both approaches fully ignored all CSS definitions found within `'& $value'`.

There are no error messages or warnings output when using the code above. After searching around through the documentation of both Material-UI and JSS I did not find any mention of known limitations relating to this scenario.

Ultimately, defining the CSS based on values provided by `StyleProperties` and the Material-UI `Theme` is a strict requirement for the interface of my application. So if you would like to suggest an alternate approach to declaring hierarchy based style rules, please keep that in mind.

**EDIT**: As requested I am providing a code sandbox to demonstrate the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bird-sklgr -- see `border` definition on line 43 and the fact it is not being applied.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Added -- https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bird-sklgr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are calling `useStyles` from both `Cell` and `Value`. This causes two different classes to be generated for the `value` rule and two different classes to be generated for the `static` rule. The `value` class generated for `Cell` is being referenced by `"& $value"` in the `static` class applied to `Cell`, but it is the `value` class generated for `Value` that is applied to the `Value` element, so it isn't matched by the descendant selector in the `static` class.

You can fix this by only calling `useStyles` in one place and passing the `value` class name down to the `Value` element as in the example below:

```js
import * as React from "react";

import { Theme, makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import clsx from "clsx";

type StyleProperties = {
  scale: number;
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: (props: StyleProperties) => {
      const size = `${2.0 * props.scale}rem`;

      return {
        position: "relative",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
        width: size,
        height: size,
        "& > div": {
          position: "absolute"
        }
      };
    },

    value: {
      color: theme.palette.text.primary,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      textAlign: "center",
      lineHeight: (props: StyleProperties) => `${2.0 * props.scale}rem`
    },

    static: {
      "& $value": {
        color: theme.palette.action.disabled,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.disabledBackground,

        border: (props: StyleProperties) =>
          `${0.0625 * props.scale}rem solid red`
      }
    }
  })
);

type ValueProperties = {
  value: string;
  scale: number;
  className: string;
};

function Value(props: ValueProperties) {
  return <div className={props.className}>{props.value}</div>;
}

type CellProperties = {
  static: boolean;
  scale: number;
};

function Cell(props: CellProperties) {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <div className={clsx(classes.root, { [classes.static]: props.static })}>
      <Value value="value" className={classes.value} scale={2.0} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Cell static={false} scale={2.0} />
      <Cell static={true} scale={2.0} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit makeStyles with nested]

Comment: That makes sense and indeed resolves my issue, thank you. The fact that some of the styles, like the color and background-color, were still being applied to the elements nested within static cells threw me off from seeing the cause of the problem.

Comment: @nxn The behavior that threw you off is due to subtleties I didn't go into. When you have a combination of static CSS properties and dynamic (i.e. prop-based) CSS properties in the same rule, JSS actually creates two separate classes -- one for the static part and one for the dynamic part. Cell and Value shared the same static class names, but the dynamic parts end up being element-specific. See the console logs here: https://codesandbox.io/s/console-logs-of-static-and-dynamic-classes-5y7ej.